# How to read checkbox in rails I get to many argument to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a select list of users which then on the submit form will send an email. Such has welcome these people to the website. The problem is I can't seem to iterate through my list of checkbox to be able to send an email to each single email. Here is my form

```
<%= form_tag(invites_path) do %>
  <% @contacts.each do |c|%>
    <div>
    <%= label_tag 'accept', c[:email] %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'accept[]', c[:email], checked = true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send Invitations" %>
<% end %>
```

Now invites_path is just where the controller is, c[:email] is the email of each users desired. Now here my controller and where i am having issues.

```
# if there is more than one checkbox selected
if not params[':accept'].nil?
  params[':accept'].split.each do |u|
  InvitesMailer.invite_confirm(current_customer, u).deliver
end
else # only one checkbox selected
  InvitesMailer.invite_confirm(current_customer,params[':accept']).deliver
end
```

Why can't i read it

If I select only one checkbox or multiple  I get the following error
`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` for this line

```
InvitesMailer.invite_confirm(current_customer,params[':accept']).deliver
```

The parameters look as follow

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dNQPNGrOsw6bxRwAYxjNrC8qoqR+A228YsmTfYUCc3Y=", "accept"=>["example@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com"],"commit"=>"Send Invitations"}
```

I also would like to note i try to follow this tutorial [Check box to send email ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978810/check-box-to-send-email-ruby-on-rails), but i am a bit confused on the checkbox

UPDATE: for my mailer controller

```
def invite_confirm(curuser,usemail)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @user = curuser

    mail to: usemail, subject: "WhereyouWhere Invitation"
end
```

Comment: It looks as though the problem might lie in your `InvitesMailer#invite_confirm` method definition - could you add that code to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you read through the following and let me know if it solves your issue.

**First is the name of the params**

I'm pretty sure there's a *hackish* way to get a param to be named as `':accept'` so it may be a valid param name but in this case, it's not what you want.  Change all instances of `params[':accept']` with `params[:accept]` or `params['accept']`.

**Second is the if block**

Change your `if` block to the following code.  Since `params[:accept]` will always be an array.  You don't need to call split on it and the else block is not needed.

```
if params[:accept].present?
  params[:accept].each do |email|
    InvitesMailer.invite_confirm(current_customer, email).deliver
  end
end
```

Comment: I just change the entire action (which is create) to the second code, just pure simple that, and it still give me a wrong number of arguments

Comment: Hmm, in that case I have no idea where your issue is.  Have you tried sending a test email to see if it works?  What rails version are you using?

Comment: i am using 3.2.8, I actually believe it could be that the mailer can only take one argument, i am testing it at the moment

Comment: nope, the mailer can take any number of arguments. can you show the stacktrace?  you might be somehow using @user in your mailer views but current_customer is nil.  it's best to pinpoint first the source of the error.

Comment: Well I just removed the second arguments and it works great, I even received the emails

Comment: I did a bit more of research for you own knownledger and seem that mailers can only send a model

Comment: That is definitely wrong. Mailers can accept any number and any kind of arguments.